# How does the OpenID 2.0 Deprication effect Google Users API?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-api-python-client

Will code that relies on the [Users API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/loginurls) to grab the email address of a Google Account be effect by [this depreciation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/open_id)?

will `user = users.get_current_user()` be enough to get back the email address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will `user = users.get_current_user()` be enough to get back the
>   email address?

It will be enough, but you need to upgrade asap because many other features would not work.

Comment: I've since upgraded to google identity toolkit.  I'm a bit disappointed that their migration plan for the users api isn't better documented.  

I'll give you the up-vote - but was really hoping someone had insight on depreciation plans.

Comment: I think that only google employers have insight on that. I'm just telling you from my experience :)